# Are objects, which are returned by browser APIs, const?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, immutability

Consider for example a [Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Position) object which I can get via an API call.

If I call the API more than once, will the API return the same (singleton) Position object each time, after it edits/updates the object's property values? Or will it instantiate and return a new object each time?

I.e. if I store the Position object, might the stored/old values be overwritten by the next API call? To avoid that possibility, must clone/copy it?

Is this behaviour defined somewhere (for all APIs or for each API)?

I guess the API (and and all APIs) returns new objects but I wonder whether I can rely on that.

Comment: it depends on the API: `getElementsByTagName()` -vs- `XMLHttpRequest` for example. 9/10 times, and from geolocation specifically, you get new clean objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API specification should tell you what happens. For example [`getCurrentPosition`](https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#position-callback) (emphasis mine):

> When called, it must immediately return and then asynchronously attempt to obtain the current location of the device.  If the attempt is successful, the `successCallback` must be invoked (i.e. the `handleEvent` operation must be called on the callback object) with **a new `Position` object**, reflecting the current location of the device.

Comment: Thanks. Combined with [dandavis comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438243/are-objects-which-are-returned-by-browser-apis-const/38438376#comment64282312_38438243) that seems like a complete answer.